# How could I make function on a module defined only if all macroses has been run?

Tags: elixir

I'm writing a module `A` which defines macroses and these macroses are used by another module `B`

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import A, only: [macross: 1]

      def call
        IO.inspect @macross_value
      end
    end
  end

  defmacro macross(value)
    quote do
      @macross_value value
    end 
  end
end

defmodule B do
  use A

  macross 6
end
```

Unfortunately, `B.call => nil` not a `6`. It's because when `def call` is running `macross` in module `B` hasn't been runned yet. How could I fix it?

How could I make function on a module defined only if all macroses has been run via `use`? Is there any more interesting solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`@before_compile`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-before_compile) to define the functions after the module has completed its initial evaluation and is about to be compiled. In the `__before_compile__/1` callback, you'll need to return an AST that defines the function.

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import A, only: [macross: 1]
      @before_compile A
    end
  end

  defmacro macross(value) do
    quote do
      @macross_value unquote(value)
    end 
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
    quote do
      def call do
        IO.inspect @macross_value
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule B do
  use A

  macross 6
end

B.call
```

```
6
```

This doesn't ensure that the macro has been called by the user at least once though. For that, you can wrap the `def call` with a check that the module attribute is defined:

```
defmacro __before_compile__(_) do
  quote do
    if Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :macross_value) do
      def call do
        IO.inspect @macross_value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, if the attribute hasn't been defined, `call/0` will not be defined on the module and you'll get:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function B.call/0 is undefined or private
    B.call()
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:376: Code.require_file/2
```